# how can i implement iterative version Logn base to power?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int powFast(int b, int e){
    if(e==1){
      return b;
      }
    else if(e%2 ==0){
         return powFast(b,e/2)*powFast(b,e/2);
         }
    else
           {
        return powFast(b,e-1)*powFast(b,1);
        }
}

main() {
int base,exp,ans;

         printf("\n\n\n\n\t\tPlease enter a number:");
         scanf("\n%d",&base);
         printf("\t\tTo what power would you like it raised?:");
         scanf("\n%d",&exp);
         ans = powFast(base, exp);
         printf("\n\t\t\%d to the power of %d is: %d",base,exp,ans);
         main();
         getch();
 }
```

Comment: What's the question? What's not working? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Paul I think he may be wondering how to implement that powFast function iteratively... Maybe.

Comment: yeah u are correct i wanna implement to fast iterative version which we may use do while, while loop & for loop . ..  but its kinda hard for me to transform it to iteration can some1 help me?

Comment: Is it possible that fastRecursive version to implement it to iterative version please?? can some answer it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
int powFast(int b, int e) {
    int p = 1;   
    while (e > 0) {
        if(e%2 != 0) {
            p = p*b;  
        } 
        e = e / 2;
        b = b * b;
    }
    return p;
}
```

No explanation, deliberately. If it's an assignment, please edit your question to say so and I'll edit this one to explain

Comment: yeah it is assignment but i knew how to explain it cuz i have already have algorithm. . .:)


oh thanks alot Paul. . ..:) 5 thumbs up . .

Comment: OK. You really should say when it is an assignment, and tell us what you've tried and where you are stuck. Anyway, you've now been given the answer to your assignment. I assume you will tell your instructor it was not your own work...

Comment: I tried this code with b=8 and e=5 and it yields a wrong value.

Comment: Blast, checked it for lots of cases too :) It's got things the wrong way about, fixing now...